# Overloading >>operator and initiatializing using an initializer list of custom type

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading, initializer-list

I've been trying to make a very simple map container and I thought it would be nice to be able to initialize it like so:

```
Hash table = {  "name1" >> value,
                "name2" >> value2,
                "name3" >> value3,
                "name4" >> value4  };
```

How I was going to go about this was by first making a pair(duo) data structure which would
keep the name and the value of each element, overload the >> operator to return a duo using the name and value parameters and make a constructor for the hash class to initialize it by using the initializer_list to construct a vector of the duo elements.Then use binary search methods to retrieve the wanted element.

Unfortunately I hit a wall from the very start.
Before I started coding everything I wanted to make sure that the overloads were used correctly and in fact it was a smart decision since apparently they are not.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

struct duo {
  duo(const std::string key,int value) :key(key) ,value(value) {};
  const std::string key;
  int value;
};

struct Hash {
  std::vector<duo> lister;
  Hash(std::initializer_list<duo> passed) :lister(passed) {};
};

duo operator >> (const std::string& id,int value) {
  return duo(id,value);
}

int main(){
  duo object1("test",1);
  Hash table = {object1};
  std::cout << table.lister[0].key << table.lister[0].value;
}
```

but this gives "invalid operands of types ‘const char [6]’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator>>’"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

struct duo {
  duo(const std::string key,int value) :key(key) ,value(value) {};
  const std::string key;
  int value;
};

struct Hash {
  std::vector<duo> lister;
  Hash(std::initializer_list<duo> passed) :lister(passed) {};
    };

duo operator >> (const std::string id,int value) {
  return duo(id,value);
}

int main(){
  Hash table = {"test1" >> 1};
  std::cout << table.lister[0].key << table.lister[0].value;
}
```

I tried to pass std::string to the >> operator because I can't overload with primitive types. It seems this is not a solution though. Is there any way to achieve the desired effect without explicitly converting the string literals to std::string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing a `string` explicitly will resolve this:

```
int main(){
  Hash table = {std::string("test1") >> 1};
  std::cout << table.lister[0].key << table.lister[0].value;
}
```

I would also have `>>` take a *reference* to a const string, not a string by value:

```
duo operator >> (const std::string& id,int value) {
  return duo(id,value);
}
```

You might think that you could avoid the explicit construction by devising something like:

```
template <size_t N> duo operator >> (const char (&ary)[N], int id)
{
  return duo (std::string (ary), id);
}
```

...or:

```
duo operator >> (const char* id, int value)
{
  return duo (std::string (id), value);
}
```

But *you can't* because C++ doesn't allow overriding `operator >>` for pointer (or any primitive) types.  If you try this, you will get a compiler error along the lines of "must have an argument of class or enum type."  In order to provide an operator overload, you must provide at least one argument which is of class- or enum-type.

---

So let's give this a bit of a think.  We can't use `operator<<` with two primitive arguments because that's not allowed.  What you really are looking for is clean initialization syntax without any explicit initialization.  The only thing that's really standaing in our way is that initialization.  So what if we try to construct something that actually employs *two* operators, but still looks clean?  What if we try to construct something like:

```
Hash table = {"test1" <MapTo> 1};
```

It's not *exactly* the syntax you wanted, but it's fairly close.  So let's try to build this:

There are two operators at work here:  `operator<` and `operator>`.  The arguments to `operator<` are the string literal `"test1` and some object named `MapTo`.  The arguments to `operator>` are whatever `operator<` returns and an integral literal, `1`.

Looking at `operator<` first, let's hack up a prototype:

```
template <size_t N> std::string operator < (const char (&ary)[N], Something op)
```

We know that we're going to want `operator>` to return a `duo`, so what does `Something` need to be in order to facilitate that?  All we really need `operator<` to do is convert the string literal to a `std::string`, so let's try:

```
class HashOperation
{
public:
  template <size_t N> std::string cvt (const char (&ary)[N]) const
  {
    return std::string (ary);
  }
} MapTo;


template <size_t N> std::string operator < (const char (&ary)[N], HashOperation op) 
{
  return op.cvt (ary);
}
```

Now we've got the `std::string`, let's build a `duo` out of that along with the int.

```
duo operator> (const std::string& key, int value)
{
  return duo (key, value);
}
```

That was pretty easy.  Let's put it all together ([Live Demo](http://ideone.com/yM1KXM)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

struct duo {
  duo(const std::string key,int value) :key(key) ,value(value) {};
  template <size_t N> duo (const char (&ary)[N], int value) : key (ary), value (value) {};
  const std::string key;
  int value;
};

struct Hash {
  std::vector<duo> lister;
  Hash(std::initializer_list<duo> passed) :lister(passed) {};
    };


class HashOperation
{
public:
  template <size_t N> std::string cvt (const char (&ary)[N]) const
  {
    return std::string (ary);
  }
} MapTo;


template <size_t N> std::string operator < (const char (&ary)[N], HashOperation op)
{
  return op.cvt (ary);
}

duo operator> (const std::string& key, int value)
{
  return duo (key, value);
}

int main(){
  Hash table =
  {
    "test1" <MapTo> 1,
    "test2" <MapTo> 2
  };

  std::cout << table.lister[0].key << table.lister[0].value;
}
```

Comment: I know that explicit converting solves the problem. I would like to know to achieve the desired effect though.

Comment: @JohnDibling I am sorry.

Comment: What is `template <size_t N>` for?

Comment: @Veritas:  See my next edit.  I may have found something close to what you want.

Comment: @Siidheesh:  This allows passing a char literal array without having it degrade to a pointer, hence keeping the size of the array intact.  Looking back it's not strictly necesarry here.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it before. Good explanation too!

Comment: Argh I love this. Best answer !

Comment: @Veritas:  Thanks, I enjoyed thinking this through and writing it up.  Note that this could be extended to a large degree.  If you have `operator>` take not a `std::string` but an `HashOperation`, then you could construct many different `HashOperation`s which do different things.

Comment: Yea combining operators like this is very interesting and it won't be the last time I'll be using them this way. Thanks for putting so much efford into this

Comment: +1, good thinking on that `<MapTo>` overload. KonradRudolph and Yakk have previously posted something [very similar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23179/named-operators-in-c), and extended it to a lot more use cases. (cc @Veritas)

Answer (score 3):

You're [trying to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae9be5f799926130) overload `operator>>` for two primitive types, `char const *` and `int`; this is [not allowed](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/intrinsics-and-operator-overloading.html) by the language. To get it to work in its current form, you'll need to explicitly create an `std::string` from the first argument

```
Hash table = {std::string("test1") >> 1};
```

Another option, of course, is to forgo this syntax for initialization, and stick to comma separated pairs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

using duo = std::pair<std::string, int>;

struct Hash {
  std::vector<duo> lister;
  Hash(std::initializer_list<duo> passed) :lister(passed) {};
};

int main(){
  Hash table = {{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}};
  std::cout << table.lister[0].first << table.lister[0].second;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the desired effect without explicitly converting it to std::string?

Comment: @Veritas I added an alternate solution, but it doesn't use your `operator>>`. I don't know of any way to make that operator work without an explicitly constructing a string.

Comment: This is what I feared. I can find many alternatives but I I will have to throw away that clean initialization look.

Answer (score 1):

You defined operator>> for std::string and int, yet you try to use it with arguments const char[] and int. You need to let the compiler know that the first argument is std::string. Try
    `{"test1"s >> 1}`

Comment: Is this standard c++? gcc won't take it and I can't find it in my references.

Comment: No it is not, so either one needs to say std::string("test1") explicitly or define the s or _s suffix.