# std::unordered_map insert error shared_ptr c++

Tags: c++, insert, unordered-map

I am using std::unordered_map for the first time and am having a problem inserting into the map I have created.

ClassA header:

```
Class ClassA
{
public:
    void func();
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ClassB>> map;
}
```

ClassA cpp:

```
void ClassA::func()
{
    map = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ClassB>>();
    map.insert("string", std::make_shared<ClassB>());
}
```

I am getting error c2664 std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> std::_Hash<_Traits>::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>,std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [17]' to 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with the `shared_ptr`, but with the `string` key.  Explicit instantiation will solve this problem.  You also need to insert a `pair` consisting of the key and the value, not a key and a value seperately:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair (std::string("string"), std::make_shared<ClassB>()));
```

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047372/overloading-operator-and-initiatializing-using-an-initializer-list-of-custom-t/21047591#21047591) for a more novel, albiet more complex solution.

Comment: Thanks, the std::make_pair made this work with or without explicit instantiation of the string key. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

initializer_list can solve your issue too.

```
map.insert( {"string", std::make_shared<ClassB>()} );
```